# Oracle Data Modeler: add initial data to tables

Tags: oracle

I've created a relational model in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.

I want to add predefined\static data that should exist in the initial clean database: enum values, fixed lists( for example: contries ) using modeler. My goal is to receive script using "DDL File Editor" tool which contains not only "create table" commands and so on, but also "inserts" with initial data.

I there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might be the easiest way would be to put the DML into the `AFTER CREATE` tab under Scripts for each table - and to make sure it's included in the DDL script.

[image]